# Undesired output (Levels) while selecting from R dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

Part of my code is similar to following:

```
id.row <- c("x1","x2", "x10", "x20")
id.num <- c(1, 2, 10, 20)
id.name <- c("one","two","ten","twenty")
info.data <- data.frame(id.row, id.num, id.name)

req.mat <- matrix(1:4, nrow = 2, ncol = 2)
row.names(req.mat) <- c("x1","x10")

p1 <- info.data$id.row %in% row.names(req.mat)

op1 <- info.data$id.num[p1]
op2 <- info.data$id.name[p1]
```

I think the code is pretty much self explanatory and am getting the results that i want. There is no problem in printing `op1` but when I am trying to get `op2` its giving me additional output (`Levels`). As,there are 1000s of rows in original `info.data` so this "`level`" is not looking nice. Is there a way to turn it off?

Comment: `data.frame(..., stringsAsFactors = FALSE)`

Comment: Possible duplicate: every R question ever

Comment: The linked "duplicate" question is quite different from this one. This is asking how to not PRINT factors, the other is asking how to remove extra factor levels that are no longer used.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe you can use `print(op2, max.levels=0)`

Comment: This suggestion worked for me when printing a factor vector.

Answer (score 0):

If you didn't want any of your variables to be factors, then

```
info.data <- data.frame(id.row, id.num, id.name, stringsAsFactors=F)
```

is a good choice. If you wanted `id.row` but not `id.name` to be a factor then

```
info.data <- data.frame(id.row=factor(id.row), id.num, id.name, 
    stringsAsFactors=F)
```

is better to set that up. If you created your data in some other way so they already exist as factors in the data.frame, you can convert them back to character with

```
info.data$id.name <- as.character(info.data$id.name)
```

If you do want `id.name` to be a factor but just want to drop the extra levels after subsetting, then

```
op2 <- info.data$id.name[p1, drop=T]
```

will do the trick.